# Android Studio : Error while Installing APKs (Path confusion from Windows to Linux)

Tags: android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

I made an Android Studio project in Windows. After installing the Linux version of Android Studio I opened the project in Linux (it said it needs to make some changes because couldn't find the files looking for). When I wanted to emulate the project, it gave the "Error while Installing APKs" error. For instance one of the `.apk` files it wanted to install was:

`/John/AndroidStudioProjects/Test/C:\Users\John\AndroidStudioProjects\Test\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk`

The problem is that it has merged the Linux and Windows paths of the file.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to clean and build again your project, or just rebuild.
Build->Clean
Build->Rebuild